# how to pass an array of pair of values cleanly

Tags: javascript

I have a function which operates on a variable number of object pairs/triples. Right now I'm passing those objects in an array of an array like `[[..],[..],...]`. This doesn't seem clean, as I need to reference those objects using array indices like `arr[i][0].doSomething()`. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Can you give some sample data? Without seeing an example it's hard to know if you could refactor your data structure

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable number of arguments if you like.

```
function func() {
    var arg;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        arg = arguments[i];
        // Handle arg        
    }
}

func([1, 2], [3, 4]);
```

As a further improvement, you could use objects instead of pairs/triples, but that all depends on the structure of your data:

```
func({prop1: 1, prop2: 2}, {prop1: 3, prop2: 4});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have objects in an array, use always the same class/type for it. That´s the best way to do it (like in Java ArrayList).